# debugging Java synchronization

Tags: java

Is there any mechanism within the Eclipse debugging environment to see the state of synchronization locks held and processes waiting?

Comment: Are you debugging a possible dead-lock?

Comment: I found an unexpected deadlock, but I had to "guess" that might
be the case from the set of inexplicably stalled processes.  There
ought to be a better way.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can show the state of object monitors in Eclipse's debugger. You can [find a short, clear tutorial here](http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t44632.html). For each thread, Eclipse can show you the monitors the thread owns and those it is waiting for.

Update 2020-01-20: The link above no longer works. [Here's a link to cached version on the Internet Archive.](https://web.archive.org/web/20150530102651/http://www.eclipsezone.com/eclipse/forums/t44632.html)

Comment: Thanks.  I can't imagine why the monitors view is off by default.

Comment: It may be, that this only works if you are looking for a deadlock caused by a synchronized statement. I'm currently looking for one caused by an `ReentrantReadWriteLock` and I don't get this kind of information form eclipse.

Comment: the link is broken,  `eclipsezone.com` doesn't seem to exist anymore

Comment: @TMG I've updated the answer with a link to the Internet Archive cached version. I don't know if the article is already outdated now or not, it's quite old.

Comment: I'm also not sure if I'm allowed to copy-paste the contents into my answer or not...

Answer (score 1):

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2081766/how-to-debug-a-deadlock-in-java-using-eclipse) you could (if you run the Sun JVM) perform the following steps:

1. launch jconsole or jvisualvm (both present in the bin-directory of your JDK-installation,
2. attach to the process you suspect has locked up
3. go to the Threads pane. There is a "Detect Deadlock" button

Answer (score 0):

Another option: I would suggest add logging in order to "debug" your code. Sometimes it will be more intuitive.