# Detecting which Java thread is intruding my method execution

Tags: jvm, jvm-arguments, java-threads

I am facing a complicated problem with my current code (which is pretty huge). To achieve my task, we had to make many method calls around 100-120 method calls (Please don't ask me why I am doing so, it is totally decoupled implementation). To give more context this is a Java swing application. When I execute 10 times my action, around 3-4 iterations time takes to complete the action is very high (by around 300 milliseconds). I tried adding more logs to find which method call is taking more time. What I am able to notice is, the spiking is not at one place always, when I add more logs, I see the spiking pushed a bit above when I removed some piece of code the spiking moved a bit below. 
This clearly shows some background thread is actually blocking my execution (may be due to thread slicing or thread starvation), anything might be reason.
Coming to the question, I don't know which background thread is interrupting me. So I would like to know if there is any way (through Java runtime parameters) so that I can print in console which thread is paused and which thread is resuming its executing?

Comment: I would make sure that gc is not occurring at the time you see a delay, you can add `-verbose:gc` to the command line.

Comment: Hi, we had that line in our boot parameters and ensured that GC is not running in between

Comment: It makes no sense to blame background threads, when obviously, your logging code changes the timing. You should simply use a profiling software instead. Besides that, what’s the problem with making 120 method calls?

Comment: @Holger We used profiling software, the spikes are jumping in different locations, time spikes in meaningless code like on setter method. That is the reason our suspicion on background thread was high.

Comment: Profiling software is capable to show you the thread’s actual processing time, not counting the time it has not a CPU. And, of course, if there were threads stealing the CPU, the profiler should show their activity.

Answer (score 0):

> To know the thread name, that call a method, try this :

```
public void myMethod(){
    String threadName = Thread.currentThread().getName();
    System.out.println("Thread name : " + threadName);
}
```

Comment: Problem is not on how to find thread name. Here we would like to know which thread is intruding in our thread.

Answer (score 0):

What I do is have a monitoring thread which periodically check that a latency sensitive task completes in time.  When it doesn't, it prints a stack trace of the thread (and possibly any other threads of interest).  This can be useful for tracking down obscure latency jitter.

Comment: Problem here is, all the threads we guessed which could intrude our process, is not the one that is intruding. We confirmed it by adding some logs to the suspicious thread while it resumes execution. Any idea whether -Djavaplugin.trace=true will be helpful over here?

Comment: Through a profiler software we found that it was due to VM Thread inside JVM. Any idea what is VM Thread?

Comment: @RengasamiRamanujam The VM Thread is used for critical stop-the-world operations such as GC and stack traces. http://blog.jamesdbloom.com/JVMInternals.html If this is high I would look at the number of threads you are using and minimise these and minimising your allocation rate e.g. create less garbage.

Comment: @RengasamiRamanujam As you have said that GC is not happening, I would look at other STW operations like system monitoring.

Answer (score 0):

The debugger of the Eclipse IDE is able to show that a thread is waiting for another one ([debugging Java synchronization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2757066/debugging-java-synchronization)). You have to stop execution at the right point of time so that you can see what's going on.

Comment: This is not a scenario where one thread waits for the other. Here one thread forcibly pauses other thread for some reason.

Comment: One could try to set conditional breakpoints in methods like Thread.suspend with a condition checking the name of thread.

Answer (score 0):

> This clearly shows some background thread is actually blocking my execution

Which mean there are other threads which are consuming all the CPU cycles and causing delays randomly. You need to monitor CPU usage of the threads and find out the culprit thread [different ways to find the thread CPU usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930915/which-java-thread-is-hogging-the-cpu)